# Difference between System.Data.SQLite.Core and Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

I tried my best googling this, no luck. Apart from the author, one is SQLite and the other is Microsoft, are there any important differences one should be aware of before making a choice?

Comment: Yes, i think it does.